# How to create Testcases and Testsuite in Webdriver in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, selenium-webdriver

I want to organize my testcases in Webdriver. Lets say I have 20 testcases in separate files, namely

```
Tc1.java, Tc2.java, Tc3.java, Tc4.java, Tc5.java, Tc6.java, Tc7.java ...Tc19.java, Tc20.java
```

and 1 testsuite file lets say 
    Ts.java.

each testcase has atleast 1 method(function).

My question is how can I call all the testcases(Tc1 to Tc20) in Ts.java ?

Also how do I pass the parameters from Ts.java to corresponding testcases. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply choose JUnit or TestNG framework and use a whole list of tools that these frameworks provide for you. Google will help you to find a lot of articles and tutorials for both of them.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Make sure TC1.java extends TestCase

```
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class TestingSuite {

  public static Test suite() {
     TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
     suite.addTestSuite(TC1.class);
     suite.addTestSuite(TC2.class);
     suite.addTestSuite(TC3.class);

  return suite;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   junit.textui.TestRunner.run(suite());
  }
}
```